# How can I read the arrow keys in a Ruby curses application?

Tags: ruby, keyboard, ncurses

I have a Ruby curses application in which I'd like to trap for the arrow keys and function keys. The problem is that some keystrokes generate multiple values when using `STDIN.getch`. When I type a 'regular' key like `a-z` I get a single value back. When I type a [F]key or arrow key I get three values back.

Is there a gem designed for handling keyboard input or a better way to accomplish reading keystrokes?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'curses'
require 'io/console'

Curses.noecho

Curses.init_screen
main_window = Curses::Window.new(24, 40, 1, 0)

num_keys = 0
loop do
   ch = STDIN.getch
   num_keys = num_keys + 1
   main_window.addstr(' key:' + ch.inspect + ' count:' + num_keys.to_s)
   main_window.refresh

   break if ch == 'q'
end

Curses.close_screen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying enabling the [keypad](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses/Window.html#method-i-keypad-3D) on the window right after you instantiate it.

```
main_window = Curses::Window.new(24, 40, 1, 0)
main_window.keypad = true
```

and then instead of using `STDIN.getch` there's a [getch](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses/Window.html#method-i-getch) method on the window as well you can use, so try changing

```
ch = STDIN.getch
```

to

```
ch = main_window.getch
```

now when I run your program, I get

> key: 259 count: 1

when I hit the up arrow instead of

> key:"\e" count 1 key:"[" count:2 key:"A" count:3